# Should I handle CODE using Javascript SDK FB.login POP-UP or is it handled automatically to gain the access_token?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-oauth

In the authentication flow documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) it mentions the CODE which is returned upon oAuth authentication.

Is this required for the Javascript SDK or is this handled automatically in the background in this code?

By "is this required?" I mean, do I have to handle this code to verify the authenticity of the request, or does the JavaScript SDK use the code automatically to gain the `access_token`.

The documentation explains the client side flow, and how to get the access token using the 'code' so until now. I've been assuming that the SDK manages this automatically in the background, because it produces an access code as `response.authResponse.accessToken`.

```
FB.login(function(response) {

    if (response.authResponse) {

        // User is logged in to Facebook and accepted permissions

        // Assign the variables required
        var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        var fb_uid = response.authResponse.userID;

        alert(dump(response.authResponse));

        // Construct data string to pass to create temporary session using PHP
        var fbDataString = "uid=" + fb_uid + "&access_token=" + access_token;
        // Call doLogin.php to log the user in
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/doLogin.php",
            data: fbDataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                // Get JSON response
                if (data.result == "failure")
                {
                    alert(data.error_message);

                    window.location.reload();

                    return false;
                }
                else if (data.result == "success")
                {
                    window.location.reload();

                    return true;
                }

            },
            error: function() {
                return false;
            }
        });

    } else {
        // user is not logged in and did not accept any permissions
        return false;
    }
}, {scope:'publish_stream,email'});
```

I would like to know, because I want to ensure that my code is secure.

Comment: @leo.vingi when I mean the CODE that comes back with from a successful response from the oAuth Dialog.  I'm referring to the documentation where it says `The OAuth Dialog will redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's browser to the URL you passed in the redirect_uri parameter with an authorization code: 
http://YOUR_URL?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER`.  But I don't actually redirect, because I'm using the `FB.login(function(response) {` POP-UP dialog, thus no redirect.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that very quickly and deleted the comment.

Comment: Apologies, I've made the pop-up more clear in the title now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

> With this code in hand, you can proceed to the next step, app authentication, to gain the access token you need to make API calls.
>
> In order to authenticate your app, you must pass the authorization code and your app secret to the Graph API token endpoint at https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token. The app secret is available from the Developer App and should not be shared with anyone or embedded in any code that you will distribute (you should use the client-side flow for these scenarios).

If you plan on using the FB.api function to make calls to their Graph API, then you need the code to get the access token. But if you only need to authenticate the user, then what you have will do that just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have until now been assuming based on the docs that it's not possible to get an access_token without the 'code'.  So the SDK must handle this exchange in the background

Comment: I might be wrong, so someone should correct me if that's the case, but personally, I've always just used the access_token I get from the FB.login function and never bothered with the CODE and it has always worked.